# How can I tell if a complex relay is intermittently failing?

Tags: relay

I have some starting issues with my car which sometimes starts fitfully.

It could be the fuel pump relay which looks like this:

[image]

Or, it could be the fuel pump itself. For the purpose of this question I would like to know how to eliminate the relay as the source of the problem. Unfortunately, as I understand it, the inside of the relay is full of complex solder joints which age over time and it can be hard to tell whether the joints are good or not.

What is the right strategy here to determine if the relay is sound? Can I put it in some kind of test harness, or is it feasible to just take apart the relay piece by piece and manually check each solder joint?

Comment: A professional mechanic would just swap out the relay and if that didn't solve it then go on to replace the more difficult and expensive bits You're trying to save $20? It could be wiring too or maybe a bad ground.

Comment: They do do that, but, especially with an intermittent fault, there are benefits to confirming that a part actually has a problem. Say that the issue is a crimp connector on the back of the relay socket which is loose. The act of swapping the relay makes it seem that everything is OK again - for two weeks and then you get a recurrence of the issue. Back to square one. Professional mechanics work on an hourly rate so will not usually go to the trouble, but is always worth confirming the cause of a problem when it is possible to do so.

Comment: If it starts poorly but then runs normally, I would expect the problem to lie elsewhere.  If the relay was misbehaving, it would probably misbehave while running, too.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the actual resistance across contacts with a meter, when energised or not. You should see either < 1 ohm (basically the same as you read with the meter leads shorted) or infinity. If you see readings fluctuating in the low ohms, the contacts are damaged and it's time to change it. If you power it from a bench supply, you can also check that the relay energises reliably from the specified voltage, if you can find the information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the relay is most likely the switching contacts themselves. If memory serves DC relays contacts have a shorter lifespan due to arcing when making and breaking contact. I believe it is caused by DC is at a constant voltage. AC on the other hand alternates between a maximum positive and a minimum negative with a point during the transition where the voltage is at zero occurring 60 times a second. This zero crossing point stops the arcing.

Comment: The DC arc is caused by constant *current* (which in turn is caused by constant voltage). AC alternates *sinusoidally* between maximum positive ... On 60 Hz systems zero-cross occurs 120 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

Those terminal numbers are explained somewhat on [wikipedia DIN_72552](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552)

`15` goes to a switched positive supply `31` to ground, `31b` through a switch to ground

`87A` and `87B`  are the outputs and should operate alternately (show +12V) according to the commands by the switch on `31b`

You could make a a test rig using using switches and lamps, that should be sufficient to determine if the contacts are working,  testing for correct behaviour could be harder unless you know what that is.